# I want to make script read the .csv file and then append new input though console

Tags: python

I want the script to read from .csv file and then append what i have entered from console to it

```
def read():

j = 0#iterator
with open(FILENAME, "r", newline="") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)



    for row in reader:
    product.insert(product[j], row)
    j = j = 1   



def write():


with open(FILENAME, "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(product)

    if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
        product_i = str(input("Input the PRODUCT name: "))
        age_i = int(input("Input the AGE: ") )
        price_i = int(input("Input the PRICE: ") )

        new_list = [product_i,age_i,price_i]

        product.extend([new_list])


        with open(FILENAME, "a", newline="") as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(new_list)
            print('Product has been added')
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please describe which problem you're running into with you current script, it's time consuming to have to read it and try to understand where it breaks.

Comment: When i uncomment the read part, instead of inserting(appending the old info that has been entered in previous runtime) it just leaves .csv empty, once it even threw Memory Error when opening .csv file